# How create two different spinner jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spinner

How can I create two different spinners with jQuery? I need different colors for each spinner.  See the picture:

[image: Here!]

I created one of them like this:

```
var spinner = $( ".spinner" ).spinner({
min: 0,
max: 9999
});
```

So, how can I change the color to blue and create another one???

Comment: couldn't you just say "color: blue"

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try to use id and create two different spinner.